# Rmarkdown - Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 43

Tags: r, r-markdown, pandoc

Before going into details I have searched several threads with a similar title and tried the answers suggested but I am unable to resolve, so the new thread.

So I have my project details in a file `*.Rmd`. I am trying to create a PDF file with this in `rmarkdown`. But it is showing the following error

`pandoc: Error producing PDF
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 43`

What I was trying to create a PDF is

`library("rmarkdown")
render("file.Rmd", "pdf_document")`

However it is creating the `html` file properly. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

BTW, I am using ubuntu 14.04, not Rstudio.

Sample content from `test.Rmd`

```
<!-- Documentation for Microarray data analysis project-->

## **Microarray Data Analysis Project**

### Establishing Gene Expression profiles of CAFs in (GBOC) cell lines

******

***Cancer Associated Fibroblasts***, like normal fibroblasts secrete growth factors for the development but
for the development of tumors. Adding to the complexity of understanding the role of CAFs, there is a lot of
inter-tumor heterogeneity in the expression of CAFs among different tumors of a same cancer type. 

#### qPCR results for a-SMA IMAGE

* Two groups - qPCR experiment.

group-1             | group-2
:-------------------------: |:------------------------:
    KV01-H          |   KV02-L
    KV08-H          |   KV05-L
    KV09-H          |   KV07-L
    KV010-H         |   AP010-L
    AP018-H         |   AP016-L
    AP024-H         |   AP020-L

To further understand the effect differential expression of CAF on other genes expression in 2 groups, a microarray.
```

Thank you.

Comment: are you using Rstudio? are you using the knit button? if not, could you add the header to your example?

Comment: No, I am not using Rstudio or knit button. Header of example? DO you mean from `file.Rmd`?

Comment: Can you provide a minimal reproducible example that triggers the error? (What are your version numbers? For example: R, `knitr`, `rmarkdown`, and pandoc.)

Comment: Yes, the header of the `file.Rmd`

Comment: @Dambo @r2evans - I've updated the question. Please refer. `pandoc` version is `1.17.0.2-1`. And how do I check the version of `knitr`?

Comment: @nEU ok I meant the very first lines of your file, where you might something like `output: html_document`. I use RStudio, but I wonder if any mismatches between what you have in `output` and the function `render` might actually generate the error.

Comment: @Dambo I do not know about Rstudio but here no need to mention specifically about `html` document as this is the default. If we need a `PDF`, we write something like `render("file.Rmd", "pdf_document")`, so it will create PDF document.

Comment: I don't think there should be any differences between RStudio, I mentioned it because I thought RStudio could somehow handle misspecification differently. What I meant with "header" is this part by the way: http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/pdf_document_format.html
And I am not sure why you would be allowed to omit it in R...